# SQL - How can i get the last two characters from a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

> users - user_info - districts

And I built a Inner join to get the user_id and the user_info.

```
Select * from users a inner join user_info b on a.id = b.user_id
```

But i have a column called location, inside the user_info, which returns the ID from a specific location. Just like this:

> 00;11

And to get the location, I have to Inner Join the user_info table, to another table called districts, because the two last characters got the ID from the district.

Thats why I would like to Inner Join all three tables, like this:

```
Select * from users a inner join user_info b on a.id = b.user_id inner join districts c on b.location = c.District_id
```

The problem is that, i want to get only the two last characters from the Location column. But i'm getting

> 00;11 //I would like to only get the 11

I will output everything later, using Json, and I would like to get the User info, and his location.

Is it possible to "substring" a column in SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: If you'd bothered to RTFM: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right

Comment: It wont be very efficient if you make a JOIN on a field using a SUBSTRING function. You'd better add a column with just the result of the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SUBSTRING_INDEX in MySQL to get the string after the semi-colon

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('00;11', ';', 2);
```

Or in your case:

```
Select  SUBSTRING_INDEX(Location, ';', 2),* from users a inner join user_info b on a.id = b.user_id inner join districts c on b.location = c.District_id
```

Alternatively you can take the last two characters of your string using RIGHT

```
SELECT RIGHT('00;11', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. See: [MySQL String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

```
mysql> SELECT RIGHT('foobarbar', 4);
        -> 'rbar'
```

For further information, please see:

[SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)
[RIGHT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right)